# Messed up Berkeley DB error message with C++ build of Fix8 in CentOS Linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, centos, berkeley-db

I built BerkleyDB successfully with the instructions found at:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/db.html

I am trying to build Fix8 (fix8.org) on my CentOS 6.3 with a required dependency of BerkleyDB but I get a failed error:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -Wall -rdynamic -o .libs/f8c f8c.o f8cutils.o f8precomp.o     
-lrt  /home/caustic/dev/dakka-fix8-b0a60e9/runtime/.libs/libfix8.so -lcrypt 
 -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -ltbb -L/home/caustic/dev/dakka-fix8-b0a60e9
 /runtime -ldb_cxx -lz -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib

 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../..
 /../libdb_cxx.so when searching for -ldb_cxx

 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libdb_cxx.so when searching for -ldb_cxx

 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb_cxx
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [f8c] Error 1
```

When I "ls" the specified  problem file, I get:

```
[root@hft x86_64-redhat-linux]# ls  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../.. /../libdb_cxx.so
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../libdb_cxx.so
 [root@hft x86_64-redhat-linux]# ls -l  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../libdb_cxx.so
 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Nov 23 17:36 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../libdb_cxx.so -> libdb_cxx-5.3.so
```

I removed all older or conflicting instances of BerkleyDB using "yum remove". IS there any hints that can get me on track with this? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you verify that your object files are built for 64 bits? It looks as if some of the code is 32 bits while others is 64 bits.